# Excel VBA copy from one sheet to other sheets specific cells based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, copy

I am trying to copy from Sheet1, specific rows when on that row a specific cell has status "DONE" selected to say, and a second criteria after "DONE" is to check if on the same row, another cell has also a specific value. After that, copy the rows found each on specific sheet, checking destination if duplicates are found.

I have managed until now to copy from Sheet1 to the other based on the 2 criteria (old school with IF, I tried with autofilter but I didn't manage to do it) but I am having a hard time preventing duplicates to be copied to the other sheets.

I tried everything, value checking based on first sheet with Range, writing a macro for each sheet so it prevents duplicates, nothing worked and i am stuck on this.

Another problem with below code is that after hitting Update button multiple times, it doesn't duplicate all found rows, but only the first one found, and also inserts some empty rows in between and I don't understand the reason for that.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, j1 As Long, k1 As Long, j_last As Long,
k_last As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long
Dim ActiveCell As String

With Worksheets("PDI details")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("Demo ATMC")
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2
End With

With Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy")
    k = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2
End With

With Worksheets("Demo SHJ")
    j1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    k1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("Demo AD")
    a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

MsgBox (j)
For i = 5 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("PDI details")
        If .Cells(i, 20).Value <> "" Then

            If .Cells(i, 20).Value = "DONE" Then
                If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "ATMC DEMO" Then

                    If Not .Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("D4") Then
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("A" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("A" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("B" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("E" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("C" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("F" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("D" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("G" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("F" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("H" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC").Range("G" & j) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("I" & i).Value

                    End If
                End If
                If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "ATMC COURTESY" Then
                    If Not .Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("D4")
                    Then
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("A" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("A" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("B" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("E" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("C" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("F" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("D" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("G" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("F" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("H" & i).Value
                        Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy").Range("G" & k) = Worksheets("PDI details").Range("I" & i).Value

                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: how do you determine a duplicate? It might be simpler to removes duplicates from the pasted to sheet rather than try not to copy them. Either way, finding duplicates is easiest when you have a single unique identifer for a row (which may be a concatenation of several columns within any given row) but that would allow you to spot if it is a duplicate (this might be the entire row is duplicated or a subset. There is remove duplicates functionality available in both VBA and via the spreadsheet direct.

Comment: And you can certainly remove some of those Ifs by combining conditions using AND

Comment: (You have a `Then` on its own line which needs to be tweaked, and you  have an errant comma after your declarations on the line `Dim i as Long, j as Long, ...`)

Comment: @BruceWayne not so much an errant comma as it is `k_last As Long` being mistakenly pushed onto the next line

Comment: you have a +2 on your last row on a few items.  Those are likely blank as the last row is the one with data.  Those are likely a culprit for your inserted blank rows.  Also you find the last row on the same sheet and column twice.  just find it once and set your second variable = to the one that found it, do you really need 2?

Comment: if you are conditionally copying rows, eventually the length of one sheet will be different from the other.  Be careful that you are keeping your row counters unique and straight on each sheet.

Comment: you are incrementing k but not j?  I will have to copy this code and work on it a bit.

Comment: i did some tests that's why i removed incrementing j . The idea is if i not add +2 on the calculating the last used row, it will override my header columns. some of the variables on the top are not used, for example k_last. Don't want to remove duplicates from the destination sheet as someone will work only on that sheet. Different persons are using the first sheet, when they click update, only the new items should be copied on the other sheets so other users will fill the remaining data. If you want i can share the xlsm via dropbox link

Comment: Also, i have an unique field on the first sheet , is the VIN number of the car list. I can try to check for duplicates on that but i've tried even comparing the source cells with this number against the destination cells and it still copies duplicates.

Comment: add the rows to a dictionary using VIN as a key then spit that out later to the other sheet? But definitely start by removing lots of those IFs so logic is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test the code suggested below but I believe that it does what you wish it to do.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 23 Dec 2017

    Dim WsPdi As Worksheet
    Dim WsAtmc As Worksheet, WsCourtesy As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, Rl As Long               ' row / lastrow "PDI details"

    Set WsPdi = Worksheets("PDI Detail")
    Set WsAtmc = Worksheets("Demo ATMC")
    Set WsCourtesy = Worksheets("Demo ATMC Courtesy")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsPdi
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 5 To Rl
            If .Cells(R, 20).Value = "DONE" Then
                Select Case .Cells(R, 11).Value
                    Case "ATMC DEMO"
                        TransferData WsPdi, WsAtmc, R
                    Case "ATMC COURTESY"
                        TransferData WsPdi, WsCourtesy, R
                End Select
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub TransferData(WsSource As Worksheet, _
                         WsDest As Worksheet, _
                         R As Long)
    ' 23 Dec 2017

    Dim Csource() As String
    Dim Rn As Long                          ' next empty row in WsDest
    Dim C As Long

    Csource = Split(",A,E,F,G,,H,R", ",")
    With WsDest
        If WsSource.Cells(R, 7).Value <> .Cells(4, "D").Value Then
            Rn = .Cells(.LastRow, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For C = 1 To 7                      ' columns A to G
                If C <> 5 Then
                    .Cells(Rn, C).Value = WsSource.Cells(R, Csource(C)).Value
                End If
            Next C
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```